# Best program practice: Dictionary or synchronized arrays

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I wanted to know what is the best, or if there is more possibilities. I am retrieving data from a DataBase and, for example, I need to store IDS and NAMES. It is better to store them on different arrays withs indexes "synchronized", for example (Vb.net):

```
Dim ids As New List(Of Integer)()
Dim sCods As New List(Of String)()

For each elem In dataBaseData
    ids.Add(CInt(elem("id")))
    sCods.Add(elem("cod").ToString())
Next
```

So I know that the id on the index on the 3rd position corresponds to the same index on the other array. Or it is better to do:

```
Dim sCods As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()

For each elem In dataBaseData
    sCods.Add(CInt(elem("id")), elem("cod").ToString())
Next
```

And now suppose that I have to store subelements too. I mean, for each id, a list of elements, so with dictionaries will be something like:

```
Dim sSubs As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))()
```

And with arrays just:

```
Dim sSubs() As New List(Of String)()
Dim sOneSub As String = sSubs(idIndex)(subIndex)
```

And then imagine there is a lot of data to retrieve. I put my examples in Vb.Net, but there are just examples.

Comment: This is going to depend on what your app is using the collection for and more generally your use case. Dealing just with the information provided, a `Dictionary<int, string>` would be the recommended route. Again there are insert/read trade-offs made with any storage medium, in memory or otherwise. If you are looking for a framework to load data from a database, may I recommend one of many ORM solutions in the market including but not limited to Entity Framework and NHibernate.

Comment: What's wrong with DataSet and Datatable objects?

Comment: Is there any reason for not storing data in a Object or a DatTable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would definitely be bad practice to store the data in separate "synchronized arrays", as you described.  There are many reasons why that would be a bad idea:

- **It's not self-documenting** - There's nothing obvious about the structure of the code that implies that item 3 in one array stores data about the same object as item 3 in another array.  So, the only way to make that obvious is to add comments to the code explaining how and why the data is stored.  While comments are definitely a good thing, not needing comments is even better.
- **You can't easily reference the data** - How do you intend to return this data from your data-access layer?  How do you intend to pass it as a parameter to a business-layer method?  To get all of the data, you'd have to pass all of the lists.  To pass a single object's data from the lists, you'd have to pass all of the data as separate variables.
- **It's not flexible** - When you store it that way, it makes it very difficult to add new properties to your objects.  For instance, right now, you may only need to store an ID and a description for each object, but what happens when you need to also store a date?  Not only would you have to add a new list/array to store the dates for all of the loaded objects, but you would have to fix everywhere that uses and passes around the data.  And how do you find all of the places in the code that you need to fix?  That won't be easy to do either, since there is no specific data-type for the object that you can search for.
- **It's brittle** - For all of the reasons already mentioned, and more, storing the data like that will lead to buggy code.  What happens if the lists get out of sync?  What happens if you fail to load the data half-way through an object, so only some of the lists get updated?  What if you need to remove an item from the list and that fails on only one of the lists for some reason?  What if multiple threads need to modify the data at the same time?  If you aren't exceptionally careful, things can go wrong very easily.  It's not necessary to make your code so brittle, so why give yourself all that hassle unnecessarily?

So what is the better solution?  Well, the `Dictionary` is definitely a better option, but in this case, it may still be misguided.  You don't need a dictionary if all you need to do is to store two data elements per object.  The purpose of a dictionary is to store key/value pairs where you need to be able to quickly access the value given the key.  The dictionary uses a hash table to index the list to make the key look-ups very quick.  But if it's not used properly, it can actually make things less efficient (viz. more memory, slower because of hash code generation).

The correct way to store data for an object, or an entity, as it is sometimes called in DB design, is to create a class.  These classes are often referred to as Data Transfer Object (DTO) classes.  For instance:

```vb
Public Class MyEntity
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Code As String
End Class
```

Then, you can easily store the data in any type of list that you want, for instance:

```vb
Dim entityArray() As MyEntity  ' Arrays are great for storing lists which don't change in length very often
Dim entityList As List(Of MyEntity)  ' Lists are great when the number of items in the list keeps changing
Dim entityDictionary As List(Of Integer, MyEntity)  ' Dictionaries are great when you need to quickly access items by their key (their ID, in this case)
Dim entityQueue As Queue(Of MyEntity)  ' Queues are great when you need to process incoming items in the order that they were received
' Etc.
```

Now, when you need to return a `MyEntity` object, you can return it `As MyEntity`.  And when you need to return a list of them, you can return them as a single list.  The same is true when passing them as parameters to methods.

Also, when you need to add a new property to your entity, you can simply add it to your DTO class, like this:

```vb
Public Class MyEntity
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Code As String
    Public LastModified As Date  ' Hey look! A new field.
End Class
```

Now all of the code that works with that data type will all instantly have access to that new property.  All you have to do is populate the field with data.  If you want to find all of the places in your code that work with that data type, just right click on the `MyEntity` class name and choose the *Find All References* option from the context menu.

As others have mentioned there are frameworks available for creating entity classes and reading and writing them to the database.  I'd say that, at the time I'm writing this, the Entity Framework and NHibernate are the two most popular options.  They are certainly worth considering, but it's always important to fully understand what a framework is doing and why you need it before you start using one.  So, I would recommend at least trying to do your data access layers properly yourself for a while before you start looking into ways to cut corners.  There's nothing wrong with using frameworks that make your life easier, but if you use any framework incorrectly or for the wrong reasons, they will likely make your life more difficult, not easier.